# How to check if a "leave" member exists without testing existence of its parents

Tags: javascript

Imagine this code:

```
var obj = {};
obj.x = {};
obj.x.y = {};

if (obj.x.y.z) {
  //the test work, I know obj.x.z.z do not exist
}

if (obj.a.b) {
  //fail because "cannot read property 'b' of undefined
}
```

The question is : How I can check the existence of a "leave" (if "b" exist, it must inside "a") without making the test of each its parents before ?

Comment: Check my answer this way you no need to figure what leave and parent are there. you can figure out passing params.

Answer (score 0):

Use to check if key exist or not.

```js
var obj = {};
obj.x = {};
obj.x.y = {};

if (obj.x.y.z) {
  //the test work, I know obj.x.z.z do not exist
}

function isExist(arg){
   try{
      return arg();
   }catch(e){
      return false;
   }
}

console.log(isExist(()=>obj.x.y))
console.log(isExist(()=>obj.x.y.z))
console.log(isExist(()=>obj.a.b))
```

Reference : [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Comment: Please flag the questions as duplicates instead of taking the answers from other questions and posting them again

Comment: Sure. Thanks will do.

Comment: Once you have 3k reputation, you can [vote to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) directly

Comment: Right now dont have that. Trying to get that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [elvis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator.

```
if (obj.a?.b) { // no error thrown
  console.log('error'); // 'error' isn't be logged
}
```

Comment: I think you mean optional chaining

Comment: this way to should know before a is exist or not. Everything you have to add if case.

Comment: No, you don't. In this case `a` is undefined so we skip the code inside if case

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal in the works for an operator that looks like `?.` called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

You would then use it on your example like

```js
obj.a?.b
```

For now though, you'll have to write more to safely access nested properties

```js
var obj = {};
obj.x = {};
obj.x.y = {};

if (obj.x.y.z) {
  //the test work, I know obj.x.z.z do not exist
}

if (obj && obj.a && obj.a.b) {
  // will not throw
} else {
  console.log('didn\'t throw!')
}
```