# How to pass multiple object attributes as parameter?

Tags: javascript

Let's use this object as example:

```
var obj = {a: {b: {c: 'result'}}}
```

I know that I can get the value of c, doing this:

```
console.log(obj.a.b.c) // 'result'
```

or this:

```
console.log(obj['a']['b']['c'])
```

but how I can get the value of c passing obj and columns as arguments in a function?

```
function func(obj, attributes) {
   return obj[attributes]
}

console.log(func(obj, a.b.c)) // how to make this work
console.log(func(obj, ['a']['b']['c'])) // or this
```

Comment: do you know lodash library ?

Comment: see this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107534/how-to-check-if-a-leave-member-exists-without-testing-existence-of-its-parents/62107585#62107585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `attributes` as `string` like `'a.b.c'`. Then split it and use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get desired value.

Test it below.

```js
var obj = {a: {b: {c: 'result'}}}
function func(obj, attributes) {
  return attributes.split('.').reduce((x, a) => x[a], obj);
}

console.log(func(obj, 'a.b.c'));
console.log(func(obj, 'a.b'));
```